# What happens between a TCP handshake and HTTP CONNECT?

Tags: networking, proxy, tcp, https

When you have a system making HTTPS requests through a web proxy, my understanding is that there is the TCP handshake between the client and the proxy, then the client sends a HTTP CONNECT to establish the connection to the end server.

I currently have a strange problem where I am seeing significant delays (~20s) between the TCP handshake and the HTTP CONNECT, where the issue pretty clearly appears to be on the client side. My *guess* is that the client is attempting to do something (not visible from any logging) which is then timing out.

I want to know what happens between a TCP connection being established and the HTTP CONNECT request. Is there DNS lookups or something like that?

---

<sub>I previously asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/1144987/1054420), but the question there was too broad and off-topic.</sub>

Comment: Well if this is HTTPS, there should be a TLS handshake in there.

Comment: @Spiff: With a normal HTTP proxy the TLS handshake happens after the tunnel to the target server was established, i.e. after the client sending the CONNECT request and getting a successful response. TLS before the CONNECT request only happens if the connection to the proxy is encrypted too (resulting in two TLS connections from the client inside each other, one to the proxy and inside it another tunneled to the server).

Comment: *"Is there DNS lookups or something like that?"* - usually not since the target server is goven in the CONNECT request so that the proxy will do the DNS lookup. But it is impossible to say from remote what a specific client does internally when nothing is visible on the network layer. It could be as simple as sleeping 20s just to annoy you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah, thanks. I now have another reason to hate proxies.

Comment: @Spiff: No need to hate proxies if you aware what they promise and what not. A HTTPS connection through a proxy has the same end to end protection as a connection without proxy. The operator of a proxy has no more or less visibility into the traffic than an ISP has. If you expect more privacy from your ISP you should not use a plain proxy, but either additionally a VPN or a proxy which provides HTTPS to the proxy itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kerberos Authentication**

In our case, the NTLM authentication is implemented, but Kerberos is not. By default, the .net clients were attempting Kerberos authentication instead of NTLM.

The reason there are no logs on the proxy is because the client is attempting to connect to various domain controllers to initiate the Kerberos authentication. As these connections all fail with timeouts, it eventually falls back to NTLM, which is what the proxy is expecting.

For .net clients using `System.Net.WebProxy`, you need to specify the authentication type in the configuration:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername, proxyPassword);
var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(proxyUrl), "NTLM", credentials);

var myProxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl)
{                   
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,                   
    Credentials = credentialCache
}

// You can then use myProxy in HttpClient instances
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what happens between a TCP connection being established and the HTTP CONNECT request. Is there DNS lookups or something like that?

Use a *packet capture* program, such as Wireshark or tcpdump or MS Network Monitor, to see what's happening. If it goes over the network, no matter what it is, you will see it in the capture.

If it turns out to be something that does *not* go over the network, then the question depends highly on the client software (mainly the OS), as tracing is inherently platform-specific. For Linux I would start with 'strace' or maybe Sysprof to get a look at what a program is doing; for Windows try 'API Monitor'.